# characteristic.getDescriptor() returns null

Tags: java, android

I am interfacing a ble pedometer to android. when i execute the following line in my setCharacteristicNotification function i get descriptor as Null

```
BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));



public static String CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG = "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
```

Why is it returning a null value ??

characteristic.getUuid()  is returning me correct value.

Comment: Try `public static final String...`

Comment: Ever find an actual solution to this, Sarao?

Answer (score 7):

seems your device doesn't support this 0x2902 BluetoothGattDescriptor  try to see all of your Descriptors:

```
  for (BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor:characteristic.getDescriptors()){
                    Log.e(TAG, "BluetoothGattDescriptor: "+descriptor.getUuid().toString());
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public final BluetoothGattCallback btleGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
 @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange( BluetoothGatt gatt,int status,int newState) { 
           if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS && newState ==   BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    discoverServices();
           }
        }
 @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt,int status) {
           BluetoothGattService service =gatt.getService(UUIDS.SERVICE_UUID);
           BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic;
           characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(UUIDS.CHARACTERSTICS_UUID);
           BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor=characteristic.getDescriptor(UUIDS.CONFIG_DESCRIPTOR);
        }  
}
```