# How to find out CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, sensors

I need the `CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG` UUID for activating notifications in my App. In the google sample app they are predefined:

```
public static String HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT = "00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
public static String CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG = "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
```

All I have is:

> - BidirectionalService : b9e875c0-1cfa-11e6-b797-0002a5d5c51b
> - Rx : 0c68d100-266f-11e6-b388-0002a5d5c51b
> - Tx : 1ed9e2c0-266f-11e6-850b-0002a5d5c51b

How do I get the UUID for:

```
mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);
BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(needed UUID here));
descriptor.setValue(enabled?BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE : new byte[]{0x00, 0x00});
mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Client Characteristic Configuration has the UUID 0x2902, or, in long form, "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" as already defined in your app.

As a side note, you can find out all supported descriptors and their UUIDs as shown in this answer from Nick Unucheck:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34181034/5185968